# Запретить повторное открытие модального окна на сайте

Tags: javascript, browsers

В проекте использую [скрипт для определения старых версий браузеров](http://www.abborges.pt/js/jReject/doc.html), который открывает модальное окно с предложением скачать браузер последней версии. Также предусмотрена возможность просто закрыть модальное окно.

Если пользователь переходить на другую страницу сайта окно появляется вновь. Возможно запретить повторное открытие окна на других страницах сайта?

**AHTUNG**

От этого скрипта пришлось отказаться, и заменить его этим [browser-update](https://browser-update.org/)

Comment: стандарт: куки, localStorage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Сделала так:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function GetCookie(name) {
        var arg=name+"=";
        var alen=arg.length;
        var clen=document.cookie.length;
        var i=0;
        while (i<clen) {
            var j=i+alen;
            if (document.cookie.substring(i,j)==arg)
                return "here";
            i=document.cookie.indexOf(" ",i)+1;
            if (i==0) break;
        }
        return null;        }
    var visit=GetCookie("Cookies");
    if (visit==null){
    //reject function
    var expire=new Date();
        expire=new Date(expire.getTime()+7776000000);
        document.cookie="Cookies=here; expires="+expire+"; path=/";
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Добавь в тот же localStorage свойство userHided = false и на кнопку jr_close слушатель который изменит значение userHided на true при клике. 
Далее, там где у тебя вызывается функция reject добавим условие (на примере из документации пример из документации)

```
$('#demo2').click(function() {
  //если userHided в локалСторедже false - показываем окно. 
  if(storage.getItem('userHided') == false){
    $.reject({
       reject: {
         твои настройки плагина
       }
    }); // Customized Browsers
    return false;
  }
});
```